# Java - two do while Loops not working with scanner

Tags: java

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class doWhileLoops 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 10:");
        int val = input.nextInt();

        do
        {
            System.out.println("Guess Again!");
            val = input.nextInt();
        }
        while(val != 5);

        do
        {
            System.out.println("Stop messing around!");
            val = input.nextInt();
        }
        while(val < 1 || val > 10);

        if(val == 5)
        {
            System.out.println("Nice guess!");
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure what is wrong with this code, I have tried to change it many ways but it just does not run how i want it to. If the user enters anything but 5 then it says "guess again", even if it is over 10 or less than 1, but until the user enters 5, does it say "stop messing around!", then if I enter 5 again, then it says "Nice guess".

Comment: Did you forget to explain what this code should be doing?

Answer (score 0):

With do-while statements you execute the code in the do block once, then you verify the condition in the while statements, so if you don't wanna execute it once before verifying i suggest you to use while instead of do-while.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like

........

```
 while(val != 5){
        System.out.println("Guess Again!");
        val = input.nextInt();

         if(val < 1 || val > 10){
                 System.out.println("Stop messing around!");
                 val = input.nextInt();
         }
    }


    if(val == 5)
    {
        System.out.println("Nice guess!");
    }
```

......

will do the expected result.